# lua filter to insert custom bibliography

Tags: lua, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Can someone help me to write a lua filter that runs over all div in a html page, extracts the one with class "bibliographie" and insert the processed bibliography (content of index.bib) ?

I've tried that, but I'm nowhere near where I want to be.
Many thanks in advance !

part of YAML :

```
bibliography: index.bib
```

part of template.html :

```
<div class="bibliographie">
<h2 class="sources-def-bib-title">Bibliographie</h2>
</div>
```

and my lua script :

```
function Pandoc(doc)
    local hblocks = {}
    for i,el in pairs(doc.blocks) do
        if (el.t == "Div" and el.classes[1] == "bibliographie") then
           table.insert(meta.bibliography, value)
        end
    end
    return pandoc.Pandoc(hblocks, doc.meta)
end
```

**EDIT**

we are developing an R package and here are the pandoc_args we used :

```
pandoc_args <- c(pandoc_metadata_arg("lang", "fr"), pandoc_args)
# use the non-breaking space pandoc lua filter
pandoc_args <- c(nbsp_filter_pandoc_args(), pandoc_args)
# hyphenations
pandoc_args <- c(pandoc_metadata_arg("hyphenopoly"), pandoc_args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this step by step, we first want to extract the div contents by filtering all div elements; a `Div` filter function can be used for that, storing the contents in a local variable. Then after that, we need to add the extracted content to the metadata; Lua filters can use a `Meta` function to access and modify just the metdata. If no explicit order is given, pandoc will filter the blocks first, then metadata, which is just what we want here.

```lua
-- This will contain the contents of the div with id "bibliographie".
local bibliographie

function Div (div)
  if div.classes[1] == 'bibliographie' then
    bibliographie = div.content
    return {} -- Removes the item from the document.
              -- Drop these lines to keep the div.
  end
end

function Meta (meta)
  meta.bibliographie = bibliographie
  return meta
end
```

This assumes that `pandoc-citeproc` has already run, so the Lua filter must be given *after* the pandoc-citeproc filter: `--filter pandoc-citeproc --lua-filter bibliographie-to-meta.lua`

The [official docs](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) have all the details if needed.

Comment: Many thanks @tarleb for the explanation ! If I want to insert the processed bibliography (ie the content of file index.bib instead of 'index.bib") ?

Comment: Ah, slightly misunderstood your question. What's the format of `index.bib`?

Comment: Your answer already helps me a lot !
`@article{floch2017standards,
  title={Standards of living and segregation in twelve French metropolises},
  author={Floch, Jean-Michel},
  journal={Economie et Statistique},
  volume={497},
  number={497},
  pages={73--96},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Pers{\'e}e-Portail des revues scientifiques en SHS}
}`

Comment: Understand, so index.bib contains BibTeX entries. Do could add `cite: '@*'` to your YAML metadata to force the inclusion of all entries in your bibliography.

Comment: I tried this but my div with classes "bibliographie" is stil empty. Maybe I have to parse index.bib ?

Comment: Can you link your project or provide a more complete example? I'm having trouble understanding the setup.